# A fast data structure for storing many unsigned long variables

Tags: c++, containers, hashtable, unordered-set, unsigned-long-long-int

In a code in C++, for each input from the user, I am generating at most 20M `unsigned long` numbers one by one and checking if they are compatible with the inputs or not. Generated numbers are totally different according to the different inputs, however, I know that at most 10% of them are `unique` numbers. So, I don't want to recheck the repetitive numbers for the performance aspects as checking numbers is a bit costly in my implementation.

Therefore, I decided to generate and store numbers one by one in a container and check if they are new, to do some other costly processes on them. I have tried many containers in C++, and finally, I found `unordered_set` the fastest in my particular case, however, it is still too time_concuming. I might be able to find the distribution of the numbers for each input, but I don't know how I can make it faster. Can I use better hash functions or even other containers?

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think 20M is the count, not the upper limit on the numbers.

Comment: `unordered_set` is the best you can do. You could improve things a tiny bit by measuring `bucket_count` after a test w/20M unique numbers, and set that bucket count in the constructor. This would prevent reallocations-as-you-go.

Comment: unsigned long (any Windows and x86-32-Unix: 32 bits, x86-64-Unix: 64 bits) or unsigned long long (always 64 bits)

Comment: Are the values uniformly distributed over the unsigned long range?

Comment: Depending on your application, you can also just store the original input numbers (or only the intermediate numbers) and do the intermediate generation and costly processing (e.g. password hashing) for one subset at a time. You would divide the range of long [long] int into intervals.

Comment: *it is still too time_consuming* -- Always must ask -- are you running an optimized build, or a "debug", unoptimized build?  And how do you know it's the container that is the issue with the speed, and not your other processing?

Comment: What is the compatibility check?

Comment: Is there ANY relationship among the generated numbers or between the generated numbers and the input number you can take advantage of? If "at most 10% are unique" you can find how many numbers you need to generate to have a 50% chance of having found all numbers, generate that many, check the set size, and repeat for the difference. This would remove a good chunk of your size checks, and potentially let you end generation early once you find 10% of your ~20,000,000.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko Hi. Yes. 20M is the count of my numbers, and not the limit. The limit is the unsigned long limit with 64 bits. Thanks for your recommendation. Do you have any examples from bucket count? Thanks

Comment: @Sebastian Hi. I am using mac, and I thought that unsigned long is always 64 bits in C++. Should I use unsigned long long?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Hi. I count them and sorted them for a special input and I realized that some types of numbers are more repetitive than others, but I believe the distribution is not uniform.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Hi. Thanks for your comment. You are right. Actually, I am not saying that the problem in my implementation is the container that is time_concuming. I only tried to say that I want to make the insertion and search faster in a good data structure.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Hi. Many thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I have to generate and check the compatibility according to special order and if I could not find the proper one continue with more numbers that will be generated according to the previous numbers. I can understand what you mean, and I will try to think more about it. Thanks.

Comment: look up the [constructor that takes the number of buckets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set). Run your test program until you have enough items, then print [`bucket_count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/bucket_count), write it down, and pass it to the constructor; run your tests again.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko I will. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I think Mac counts as 64-bit Unix. unsigned long long is the compatible option. Or uint64_t.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks for your reply.